# How i can take all managed version dependencies from Spring Dependencies Managment Plugin within my custom plugin?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-plugin, spring-io

I'm writing my custom java gradle plugin for checking dependencies. Also i apply 
[Spring Gradle Dependency Managment plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin). But i cannot take a list of managed library version from this plugin. I use the next code:

```
import io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.dsl.DependencyManagementExtension;
import org.gradle.api.Action;
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.*;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyDependencyManagementPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    public void apply(Project project) {

        for (Configuration config : project.getConfigurations()) {

            config.resolutionStrategy(
                    strategy -> {
                        final DependencyManagementExtension container = project.getExtensions().getByType(DependencyManagementExtension.class);
                        Map<String, String> managedVersions = container.getManagedVersions();
                        System.out.println("Libraries from Spring Dependency Management Plugin: " + managedVersions.toString());

                        strategy.eachDependency(new Action<DependencyResolveDetails>() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(DependencyResolveDetails dependencyResolveDetails) {

                                System.out.println("!!!! " + dependencyResolveDetails.getRequested().getGroup() + ':' + dependencyResolveDetails.getRequested().getName() + ':' + dependencyResolveDetails.getRequested().getVersion() + " -> " + dependencyResolveDetails.getTarget().getVersion());

                            }
                        });
                        strategy.failOnVersionConflict();
                    }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In my test project i use including Spring framework:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.5.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

But after applying my task, it always returns empty map. Also if i call **dependencyManagement** task from io Spring Dependency Management plugin it also returns empty list.
If i don't invoke **etManagedVersions()** from my custom plugin,  **dependencyManagement** task from io Spring Dependency Management plugin works fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're calling `getManagedVersions()` before anything's had a chance to configure any dependency management. Try deferring that logic by using `beforeResolve` on the `Configuration`

Comment: Yes, you are right absolutely. If i apply my pligin in the end of build script everything works fine. Thank you